# Passing in ID for a firestore document converting to a freezed data class (fromJson)

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, freezed, flutter-freezed

What is the best way to return a document from firebase when the `id` is not coming from the json firestore returns, using a freezed data class with `fromJson`/`toJson`?

I want the `id` to be required (to make sure I always have one - and plan to use an "uninstantiated ID" for objects that haven't been saved to firestore yet).

But if I mark `id` as required, but ignore it for json generation, the `fromJson` doesn't work when I try to do code generation. Is there a way to have code generation work where I specify a second parameter in the `fromJson` method to pass in id separately?

Here is my base data class:

```
@freezed
class Habit with _$Habit {
  const Habit._();

  const factory Habit({
    @JsonKey(includeFromJson: false, includeToJson: false) required String id,
    required String title,
    String? description,
  }) = _Habit;

  factory Habit.newEmpty({required String userId}) => Habit(
        id: uninstantiatedId,
        title: '',
      );

// Ideally would like to have this take a string
// id in addition to the json, and set the id to
// what is passed in separately.
  factory Habit.fromJson(String id, Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$HabitFromJson(json);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on the other answer to this question. Maybe create two methods? `fromJson` that ignores `id` field entirely and `fromDocument` that takes in the entire `DocumentSnapshot` as an argument and extracts the `id` and `json` data from there.

```dart
@freezed
class Habit with _$Habit {
  const Habit._();

  const factory Habit({
    @JsonKey(includeFromJson: false, includeToJson: false) @Default(uninstantiatedId) String id,
    required String title,
    String? description,
  }) = _Habit;

  factory Habit.newEmpty({required String userId}) => Habit(
        id: uninstantiatedId,
        title: '',
      );

  factory Habit.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json) => _$HabitFromJson(json);

  factory Habit.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    if (doc.data() == null) throw Exception("Document data was null");

    return Habit.fromJson(doc.data() as Map<String, Object?>).copyWith(id: doc.id);
  }
}
```

Comment: That's a good idea - I think I ended up doing something similar, with `fromFirestore` as my other method name. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I can't do it with the `id` property set as non-nullable but without a default value. I either need to make id a nullable `String?` type, or set a `@Default('textvalue')` for the id.

Then I can add the `copyWith` method to my `fromJson` method which seems to work. Updated code below:

```
@freezed
class Habit with _$Habit {
  const Habit._();

  const factory Habit({
    // I have to add a default value, as pictured below, or set this to
    // String? so it is optional. Otherwise the json_serializable code
    // will not be generated.
    @JsonKey(includeFromJson: false, includeToJson: false) @Default(uninstantiatedId) String id,
    required String title,
    String? description,
  }) = _Habit;

  factory Habit.newEmpty({required String userId}) => Habit(
        id: uninstantiatedId,
        title: '',
      );

    // I then add the copyWith to my fromJson portion to add the id
  factory Habit.fromJson(String id, Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$HabitFromJson(json).copyWith(id: id);
}
```